# No click events working when switching between 2 fragments with listview's in android xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, fragment

My problem happens when switching between fragments. If I switch from a fragment without a listview to either of these, it works fine. Once I switch from fragment A to fragment B, no touch/click events work on fragment b. But, if I go from fragment B to fragment A, fragment A still works fine.

Anyone have any idea what would be causing this?

First fragment xml (Fragment A)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/tmp_lv_er_List"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Second xml fragment (Fragment B)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the main view xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
          android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
          android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
          android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
          app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/user_profile_scrollView"
    android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <FrameLayout
              android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </ScrollView>
  </LinearLayout>
  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="start"
      android:background="@android:color/white"
      android:id="@+id/nav_view"
      app:menu="@menu/navmenu"
      app:headerLayout="@layout/header" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is my show fragment code in C#

```
    private Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment mCurrentFragment;
    private Stack<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment> mStackFragments;

    //Fragments
    private WorkorderFragment woFragment;
    private ProfileFragment pFragment;
    private ClockInOutFragment cioFragment;
    private ExpenseReportFragment erFragment;
    private SettingsFragment sFragment;

    public FragmentController(MainActivity activity)
    {
        this.activity = activity;
        InitializeFragments();
        LoadFragments();
        mCurrentFragment = woFragment;//Set current fragment
    }

    private void InitializeFragments()
    {
        //Initialization
        woFragment = new WorkorderFragment();
        pFragment = new ProfileFragment();
        cioFragment = new ClockInOutFragment();
        erFragment = new ExpenseReportFragment();
        sFragment = new SettingsFragment();
        mStackFragments = new Stack<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment>();
    }

private void LoadFragments()
    {
        //Fragment init
        var trans = activity.SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();

        trans.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, woFragment, "WorkorderFragment");
        //trans.Hide(woFragment);

        trans.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, cioFragment, "ClockInOutFragment");
        trans.Hide(cioFragment);

        trans.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, erFragment, "ExpenseReportFragment");
        trans.Hide(erFragment);

        trans.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, pFragment, "ProfileFragment");
        trans.Hide(pFragment);

        trans.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, sFragment, "SettingsFragment");
        trans.Hide(sFragment);

        trans.Commit();
    }

private void ShowFragment(Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment)
    {
        if (fragment.IsVisible)
            return;

        var trans = activity.SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();

        trans.SetCustomAnimations(Resource.Animation.abc_slide_in_bottom, Resource.Animation.abc_slide_out_top, Resource.Animation.abc_slide_in_top, Resource.Animation.abc_slide_out_bottom);

        fragment.View.BringToFront();
        mCurrentFragment.View.BringToFront();

        trans.Hide(mCurrentFragment);
        trans.Show(fragment);

        trans.AddToBackStack(null);
        mStackFragments.Push(mCurrentFragment);

        trans.Commit();
        mCurrentFragment = fragment;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo to reproduce this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, changing the order of the ExpenseReport fragment in the LoadFragments() method fixed the problem. Really strange.

```
    private void LoadFragments()
    {
        //Fragment init
        var trans = activity.SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();

        trans.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, woFragment, "WorkorderFragment");
        //trans.Hide(woFragment);

        trans.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, erFragment, "ExpenseReportFragment");
        trans.Hide(erFragment);

        trans.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, cioFragment, "ClockInOutFragment");
        trans.Hide(cioFragment);

        trans.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, pFragment, "ProfileFragment");
        trans.Hide(pFragment);

        trans.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, sFragment, "SettingsFragment");
        trans.Hide(sFragment);

        trans.Commit();
    }
```